# Match a partial folder name in Gulp

Tags: gulp

Why does this work:

```
gulp.src('./tmp/downloads/bootstrap*')
  .pipe(unzip())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'))
gulp.src('./tmp/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/bootstrap'))
```

but this does not:

```
gulp.src('./tmp/downloads/bootstrap*')
  .pipe(unzip())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'))
gulp.src('./tmp/bootstrap*/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/bootstrap'))
```

I would like to get all the folders and files under `./tmp/downloads/bootstrap<version>` and move them to `./dist/bootstrap`. I have tried many configurations, and either the folder get there but the files don't, the files get flattened into one folder, or the whole folder `bootstrap<version>` gets copied into `./dist/bootstrap/bootstrap<version>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `bootstrap**` to match directories starting with `bootstrap`:

```
gulp.src('./tmp/downloads/bootstrap*')
  .pipe(unzip())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'))
gulp.src('./tmp/bootstrap**/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/bootstrap'))
```

Comment: This represents one of the cases where it does match the directory itself, not the contents. This ends up creating `dist/bootstrap/bootstrap<version>/`.

Comment: That is a problem with the output method, not with the matching. You can verify that your are matching what you expect by using `glob` directly. e.g. `glob.sync('./tmp/bootstrap**/**/*')`.

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue. Perhaps I am unclear. I want to match `./tmp/bootstrap<version>` and output to `./dist/bootstrap`.